# Add webparts to an existing spfx solution after deployment

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I added a new webpart to a spfx solution after it has been deployed to SP online. I repackaged the solution, reuploaded the package to the app catalog and I do not see the newly added webpart in the "Add Webpart" gallery. I completely deleted the app fromt he site and recycle bin and readded the app and the new eb part showed up. Is this(deleting the app and readding) the only way to make newly added webparts in the solutions showup on the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, before packaging, you need to increase the solution version number in the `package-solution.json`. (also make sure your new components are listed in the `config.json`)
Then bundle the solution and install it into the app catalog (drag and drop the sppkg file).
Once that is done, on the sites you already installed the solution on, you should be able to upgrade the solution (by going to the site collection, site content, clicking on the … next to the solution name and details).
Once the upgrade is done, the new webparts should be available.
As mentioned by Brannmar, you might also need to deploy latest javascript files manually if those are not deployed automatically with the package. This is the case if your `deploy-azure-storage.json` and `write-manifest.json` are configured and if you don't have `"includeClientSideAssets": true,` in your `package-solution.json`.
[Here is a link to the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/enterprise-guidance#deploying-sharepoint-framework-solutions)

Comment: also mention that the js files need to be updated. If its not included in the package

Comment: That's right, however it depends on the version of the sharepoint framework the project was started on

Comment: Absolutely, but at least mention it. Exactly as you stated here. I think your answer were better than mine.

Comment: The process of upgrading the version is a bit painful when you have deployed the solution to several tens/hundereds of sites and you add a new webpart to the solution. This will require manual upgraded on each of these sites. According to the documentation here : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/alm-api-for-spfx-add-ins there is an API as well to do this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the article from Microsoft it should be to bundle the new js files and then create a new package and upload them both to where they belong.

[Deploying SharePoint Framework solutions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/enterprise-guidance#deploying-sharepoint-framework-solutions)

If this is what you have tried, there may be some sort of cache issue?